Polynomial time algorithms for graphs and cycles
For a given undirected graph  $G$ , let $ c(G) $ denote the length of the longest cycle in $ G $ (by cycle, we mean a closed path without repetitions). Prove that if there exists a polynomial-time algorithm that, for every graph $ G $, returns some cycle in this graph with length at least $ \frac{c(G)}{2} $, then there also exists a polynomial-time algorithm that, for every graph $ G $, returns some cycle in this graph with length at least $ \frac{c(G)}{\sqrt{2}}-1 $.
I think the idea is to modify the input graph and run the first algorithm on it. But I have no idea how exactly input should be modified... Where does $\sqrt{2} $ come from? Maybe graph product should be considered?

Where did you encounter this task?  Can you credit the original source?

@Minko_Minkov $\left\lfloor\frac{c(G)}{2}\right\rfloor$ is smaller than $\left\lfloor\frac{c(G)}{\sqrt{2}}\right\rfloor - 1$ when $c(G)\ge 9$.
